# Bootable USB error dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my desktop, along side with a fresh install of windows. However, after selecting "Install Ubuntu", the Ubuntu loading persists and the error upon clicking F6, says, no media found. The screenshot is below.

How can I solve this issue?

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Since you have Windows, how did you closed that? Shutdown for fast startup or a restart? Do you have a partition empty?

Comment: If new system, did you install Windows in UEFI boot mode? Both Windows & Ubuntu install in mode UEFI or BIOS, that you boot install media. Have you updated UEFI from your vendor for your model. And if SSD, you probably need SSD firmware update also.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi